# Fill a web form in an external Internet Explorer instance programmatically

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, autofill

We are currently using jQuery to populate web forms. jQuery receives its information from parsing the results of an executed php script. This works, but is completely dependent on the web server being accessible and functional.

We'd like to see how to consolidate this and create a C# console, WinForms application - or possibly a toolbar/IE addon of sorts down the road.

Right now we are trying to figure out how we can interact with an external Internet Explorer process (most examples we see are in regards to WebBrowser controls). We're ultimately wanting to fetch elements by name/id and populate them with text. From an end-user standpoint, we want to mimic the functionality of roboform.

We are not interested in form submission - just acqusition of the proper instance of IE and form population.

Are there any resources you could point us to that would have an example similar to our desire?

Comment: You may have to resort to actual memory manipulation here, I'm not sure if there's any other way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'd be curious to see how Roboform does it as that was the idea we had (except this wouldn't be for login/authentications)

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible, I did that for IE7: [How to connect to a running instance of Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176792). I haven't verified if it still works for IE8+. You may also have some luck using this technique: [How to get IHTMLDocument2 from a HWND](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232).